# OctoberCMS "unique" vaidation rule does not accepts all conditional clauses while updating

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have a backend form in my model, with "unique" validation rule, the validation works good when a new record is being created but when the same record is being updated the "unique" validation fails to include all the where conditional clauses.

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
   $this->rules['product_name'] = 'required|unique:products,product_name,NULL,id,product_type_id,'.$this->product_type_id.',product_for,'.$this->product_for;      
}
```

// Above unique validation performs its functionality perfectly while creating a new record, but while **updating a new record** it **fails** to include the conditional clause for **"product_for"** column